# Synchronization between two processes in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application, on a button click I starts 2 process (P1 and P2), both runs on command propmt and I am able to redirect the output of both process to the TextBox in my WPF application.
(reading output asynch).

But the output is getting mix because I am not doing WaitForProcess neither for P1 nor for P2 (I dont want UI to get hang).
I want P2 to start after P1 gets over.

For That I am checking if Process P1 exists or not then only start Process P2.
But my UI gets hangs and nothing is coming up.

in the Windows Task bar
Process P1 is running but Textbox is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialise a `Process` object, you can register a handler for the [`Process.Exited` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As you might imagine, this event gets raised when the relevant process gets terminated, so you can start your second `Process` from there:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
...
process.Exited += Process_Exited;
```

...

```
private void Process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // First Process has completed - start second process here
}
```

Comment: Remember to set [EnableRaisingEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents) to true

Comment: @Sheridan, Thanks for help, added enableRaisingEvents to true and register exited handler, but exited event is not getting fired. :(

Comment: Thanks, @rene... apparently I accidentally stripped out too much irrelevant code... not *all* irrelevant then.

Comment: Sorry @atulya, that's not within my control. This is the normal way to handle this situation. I suppose that you could potentially take note of the process ID and use a `DispatcherTimer` to check to see if it is still running at regular intervals instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, tried this thing also -- Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate { ExecuteSonarRunner(batfile); } ), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, null);  --- But not getting event.

Comment: got workaround- I was displaying the console output to textbox, so I added the filter for some string when process P1 gets completed.